# vb.net how to loop through a directory listing?

Tags: vb.net

How can I loop through a folder getting each file listed and when its date/time?

Comment: Why does this question have upvotes even though it shows no code or no research effort...?

Comment: My guess? Because sometimes it's about the usefulness of the question and the answer that it generates, even if it doesn't adhere to the guidelines. I didn't upvote it but with 24,288 views at the time of writing I'm unsurprised that a few people did.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use DirectoryInfo.GetFiles() and extract the data (Name, CreationTime, etc.) from the FileInfo class.

I've pasted some code from the MSDN page [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4cyf24ss.aspx).

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Public Class GetFilesTest
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        ' Make a reference to a directory.
        Dim di As New DirectoryInfo("c:\")
        ' Get a reference to each file in that directory.
        Dim fiArr As FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
        ' Display the names of the files.
        Dim fri As FileInfo
        For Each fri In fiArr
            Console.WriteLine(fri.Name)
        Next fri
    End Sub 'Main
End Class 'GetFilesTest
```

Comment: how do I get the DateTime of fri? And copy it to another folder?

Comment: fri.CreationTime will give you the date/time when the file was created. To copy the file to another directory you can use the shared Copy method on the File class - File.Copy(fri.FullName, "C:\SomeDir\File.exe"

Answer (score 5):

```
 For Each LogFile In Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath & "\Txt\")

        ' do whatever wtih filename

    Next
```

Comment: This is only partial answer. Why answer like this 3 years later when there is complete answer already?

Answer (score 2):

we have the chance to develop in VB.Net (not in Java) and some variable's definitions can be shortened.

I still use GetFiles() and I have added the code to display the DateTime infos.

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
...
Dim dir As New DirectoryInfo(sFolderName)
For Each f In dir.GetFiles()
    Console.WriteLine(">> FILE-NAME: [" & f.Name & "]")
    Console.WriteLine(">> UPDATE-DATE: " & f.lastWriteTime.toString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
    Console.WriteLine(">> CREATE-DATE: " & f.creationTime.toString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
Next
```