# CRC32 from file VB

Tags: vb.net

I need some help to make this code work.
My question, how to build this code, into my exist code without using "Public Function" Or better if I call it GetCRC32("Something.exe")? How can I check multiple files with it?

```
Public Function GetCRC32(ByVal sFileName As String) As String
    Try
        Dim FS As FileStream = New FileStream(sFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 8192)
        Dim CRC32Result As Integer = &HFFFFFFFF
        Dim Buffer(4096) As Byte
        Dim ReadSize As Integer = 4096
        Dim Count As Integer = FS.Read(Buffer, 0, ReadSize)
        Dim CRC32Table(256) As Integer
        Dim DWPolynomial As Integer = &HEDB88320
        Dim DWCRC As Integer
        Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, n As Integer

        'Create CRC32 Table
        For i = 0 To 255
            DWCRC = i
            For j = 8 To 1 Step -1
                If (DWCRC And 1) Then
                    DWCRC = ((DWCRC And &HFFFFFFFE) \ 2&) And &H7FFFFFFF
                    DWCRC = DWCRC Xor DWPolynomial
                Else
                    DWCRC = ((DWCRC And &HFFFFFFFE) \ 2&) And &H7FFFFFFF
                End If
            Next j
            CRC32Table(i) = DWCRC
        Next i

        'Calcualting CRC32 Hash
        Do While (Count > 0)
            For i = 0 To Count - 1
                n = (CRC32Result And &HFF) Xor Buffer(i)
                CRC32Result = ((CRC32Result And &HFFFFFF00) \ &H100) And &HFFFFFF
                CRC32Result = CRC32Result Xor CRC32Table(n)
            Next i
            Count = FS.Read(Buffer, 0, ReadSize)
        Loop
        Return Hex(Not (CRC32Result))
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ""
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: If I am understanding what you need to do, [check this directory loop out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216101/vb-net-how-to-loop-through-a-directory-listing)  but instead of `Console.WriteLine(fri.Name)`  you'd want to use `Something(x) = GetCrc32(fri.Name)`.  Where Something is a [list of strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: So for example Dim file as String =GetCRC32(file)?

Comment: Each file will generate a string, you'd want to create a loop that calls GetCRC32 on each pass, for each file, and store it in a list.  So it'd be easier to say at that point `listFiles.add(GetCrc32(thisFile))` for each pass of the loop if that makes sense?

Comment: If you want to get rid of the question, there is a delete link by the tags.